# Как отключить подсветку синтаксиса и автодополнение скобок в Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Здравствуйте, как в eclipse можно отключить подсветку синтаксиса, как при редактировании так и после компиляции. Так же можно ли отключить авто закрывающиеся "{}" "()". Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window-Preferences-Java-Editor-Typing-Automatically close. Выбрать что включать/отключать. Для скобок.

Window-Preferences-Java-Editor-Syntax Coloring. Для подсветки.
[image]

Comment: Для скобок помогло, а для отмены подцветки ошибок нет, напишите пожалуйста подробнее, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Наверное, в в начале не правильно выразился, мне нужно отключить выделение ошибок(волнистой линней снизу)

Comment: а для чего вам тогда вообще ide ? пишите в обычном текстовом редакторе или в vim

Comment: Нужно, а зачем долго объяснять.

Comment: Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors поробуйте

Comment: Большое спсибо, все получилось.